# Some times oc.lazyLoad not working properly in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, lazy-loading, oclazyload

Am working on the Angularjs project in which there is requirement to load the css and js files on demand, For this purpose i used the oc.lazyLoad library in angularjs, but some times pages loaded fines and some times it produce errors with loaded files. Following are my code:

```
    .state('datetimepickers', {
        url: "/date-time-picker",
        templateUrl: "views/date-time-picker.php",
        data: {pageTitle: 'Date-Time Pickers'},
        controller: "DateTimePickerController", 
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'datetimepicker',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files
                    files: [
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/css/daterangepicker.css',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/css/clockface.css',

                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/clockface.js',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/moment.js',
                        'assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/daterangepicker.js',

                        'js/controllers/DateTimePickerController.js'
                    ] 
                });
            }]
        } 
    })
```

some times its works just fine , but when page reload it produce errors like:

Error: moment is not a function
DateRangePicker@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/daterangepicker.js:34:26
$.fn.daterangepicker/<@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/daterangepicker.js:1615:40
.each@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:2859
n.prototype.each@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2:843
$.fn.daterangepicker@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/bootstrap-datepicker/js/daterangepicker.js:1611:9
@http://localhost/angular/angular/js/controllers/DateTimePickerController.js:132:5
vf/this.$gethttp://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:147:42
k@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23267
y/k.compile/http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:23401
vf/this.$gethttp://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:147:483
v/y.transitionTo/y.transition<@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:18767
e/<@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:130:409
vf/this.$gethttp://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:145:103
vf/this.$gethttp://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:142:165
vf/this.$gethttp://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:145:399
l@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:97:248
K@http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:101:373
gg/http://localhost/angular/angular/assets/global/plugin/angularjs/angular.min.js:102:397

Comment: Something wrong with path ?